# Is it possible to use LOAD DATA INFILE with SELECT / WHERE (like a INSERT ... SELECT)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a college table and a department table. The college table has two columns: id and name, and it has some rows:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id |          name           |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | College of Engineering  |
|  2 | College of Science      |
|  3 | College of Business     |
|  4 | College of Liberal Arts |
+----+-------------------------+
```

The department has three columns: id, name and college_id

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | college_id |
+----+------+------------+
```

Now I have a csv file, which contains a list of departments and the name of their college:

```
Department of Computer Science, College of Engineering
Department of Mathematics, College of Science
Department of Histiry, College of Liberal Arts
```

Now I want to load the csv file into the department table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but the departbemt table requires  the college_id whereas the csv file has only the college name. Is it possible to get the id of the college in the `LOAD DATA INFILE` clause?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you load it in to a temporary table (or create a temporary column) and manipulate it from there?

Answer (score -1):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to .csv' INTO TABLE college
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(name)
```

I hope id is auto_increment. Create College table using this idea, after this create a temp table with all the columns in the csv file. Then using temp table and college table you can fill department table.

Comment: That was an example! I was explaining in general!

Comment: why are you providing general queries when OP has clearly provided details of his tables. Please try to construct queries for OP's particular context. It'll help make your answer more relevant (and better IMO)

Comment: Please see my edit and verify if it conforms to what you're trying to convey :) (feel free to revert)

Comment: It is exactly what i wanted to explain :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53834/discussion-between-raghavpotluri-and-ejay)